# How to create a table in mysql where the number of fields in the table equals the number of columns in the excel file in php?

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

I want to create a table in mysql where the number of fields in the table equals the number of columns in the excel file.

```
$sSql = "";
for ($col = 1; $col <= $nrColumns; ++ $col) {
   if ($col < $nrColumns){
      $sSql = $sSql . " Kol[$col] VARCHAR(25), ";
   } else {
      $sSql = $sSql . " Kol[$col] VARCHAR(25)";
   }
}
echo "SQL = $sSql <br>";

$sqlCreate="CREATE TABLE temp_table ( $sSql )";

$result = mysql_query($sqlCreate, $connect);
if (!$result){
  die('Could not create table: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

I try that code, but not working. 
Thank you.

Comment: Isn't the number of columns in excel pretty much unlimited? :P Anyway, the "Kol[$something]" part looks suspicious, I've never seen such thing in a mysql query.

Comment: So what does that `mysql_error()` output? I'd say it complains about the square brackets inside the column names...

Comment: Not whole columns of course.

Comment: What should that mean: "Not whole columns of course." That certainly is _not_ the output of `mysql_error()`.

Comment: $highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);
    $nrColumns = ord($highestColumn) - 64;

Comment: that is for MightyPork. Error: Could not create table: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[1] VARCHAR(25), Kol[2] VARCHAR(25), Kol[3] VARCHAR(25))' at line 1

Comment: Yep, just as expected. MySQL actually _tells_ you what the problem is: your square brackets! See my answer below I wrote a few minutes ago. And a hint for future questions you want to ask: such error output is really important to be incuded unaltered inside the question. Your generic "but not working" is not a helpful replacement for it.

Comment: @Baskoro: Answer may help. I have slightly reframed your code.

Comment: `$highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn); $nrColumns = ord($highestColumn) - 64;` will only work if you have less than 26 columns in your worksheet.... `$highestColumnIndex` should be the correct value without any need to faff around with `ord`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the column name syntax you chose: square brackets are not valid inside column names. So `Kol[$col]` is invalid, you can do something like `Kol_$col` instead.

For reasons of coding style I would advise to use `sprintf()` for this:

```
$sSql .= sprintf( ' kol_%s VARCHAR(25)', (int)$col );
```

Also note the lowercase 'k' in the column name. It has proven to prevent annoying errors *not* to user uppercase characters in identifier names.

You can simplify your code by using phps `implode()` function, btw:

```
$sCol = array();
for ($col = 1; $col <= $nrColumns; ++ $col)
   $sCol[] = sprintf( 'kol_%s VARCHAR(25)', (int)$col )
$sqlCreate = sprintf( 'CREATE TABLE temp_table (%s)', implode( ", ", $sCol ));
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit of restructing your code. Try the following -

1) Convert your excel file to csv.

2) Run the function `csv_to_array()`
     
         **input** - filename.csv
     
         **output** - array of column names

3) Run the `foreach()` loop

```
function csv_to_array($filename='', $delimiter=',')
{
   if(!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename))
      return FALSE;

   $header = NULL;
   $data = array();
   if (($handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== FALSE)
   {
      while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE)
      {
         $data = $row;
         break;         
      }
      fclose($handle);
   }
   return $data;
}

$columns = csv_to_array("myfile.csv");

$sql = "";
foreach($columns as $col)
{
  $sql .= $col." VARCHAR(25), ";
}

$query = "CREATE TABLE table_name 
          id int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          $sql
          PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
         ";

$result = mysql_query($query, $connect);
if (!$result)
{
   die('Could not create table: ' . mysql_error());
}
```